Summarize multiple columns using colSums2 and lapply
I'm trying to summarize some columns using the matrixStats package and lapply inside data.table
library(data.table)
library(matrixStats)
set.seed(100)
n = 100
dd = data.table(row_id = 1:n, person=rep(1:20,5), val = runif(n, 10, 50), val2 = runif(n, 20, 40))
dd[, lapply(as.matrix(.SD), colSums2, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("val","val2"), keyby = "person"]

doing the above I get
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Argument 'dim.' must be an integer vector of length two.

I read the package docs but still can't understand what should I do. I know I can do
dd[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("val","val2"), keyby = "person"]

but I want to understand this error with matrixStats because I will need to use the package in other situations

lapply on a matrix will operate on each element, not on columns.
Try, for example:
dim(dd[, lapply(as.matrix(.SD), \(x) x)])
#> [1]   1 400

Here, lapply returns a list of length 400, which gets converted into a 400-column data.table as it is inside the j argument.
Maybe you are trying to do something like this (although in this case, colSums2 is not the best solution):
dd[,as.list(colSums2(as.matrix(.SD))), .SDcols = c("val","val2"), keyby = "person"]
#> Key: <person>
#>     person      val     val2
#>      <int>    <num>    <num>
#>  1:      1 133.8986 150.0228
#>  2:      2 173.2038 143.1089
#>  3:      3 199.9420 141.2131
#>  4:      4 181.6752 153.7968
#>  5:      5 128.9970 126.4219
#>  6:      6 133.2854 139.0593
#>  7:      7 192.0843 161.3366
#>  8:      8 163.2263 150.4124
#>  9:      9 123.9679 132.8353
#> 10:     10 137.3156 150.6447
#> 11:     11 160.5209 160.1922
#> 12:     12 151.8757 168.9525
#> 13:     13 121.8177 134.9162
#> 14:     14 171.7132 153.8851
#> 15:     15 194.6941 172.1213
#> 16:     16 163.0401 129.8800
#> 17:     17 125.3048 166.1822
#> 18:     18 134.6736 156.1893
#> 19:     19 162.4315 125.2364
#> 20:     20 125.8121 171.2547
#>     person      val     val2


lapply function is designed to work on list object and not on matrix. It applies the specified function on each element of the list; and whenever a non-list element is used, it is first coerced to a list (internally) before applying the specified function on each of its elements.
Because you passed on a matrix instead of list in your example, it is internally coerced to a list. And when a matrix is coerced to a list, each of its values becomes an element in the list created. Each value becomes a list element because a matrix is internally a vector (with a special attribute: "dim").
After each value of the matrix becomes an element in the created list, lapply attemps to apply colSums2 on each of its elements; and because each element is a single number, colSums2 fails to work because it expects a matrix (an object with 2 dimensions).
The r built-in function designed to work with matrix (and not list) is apply. It is similar to lapply but has an additional argument (MARGIN) useful to specify if the specified function should be applied column-wise or rowwise. Note that it internally coerces its input to matrix when it is a data.frame. So, apply(df, ...) is equivalent to apply(as.matrix(df), ...) when df is a data.frame.
